# How can I use selenium in python to select an item in a dropdown when the options are non-interactable <div> boxes?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to make a program that runs through the infamous https://userinyerface.com/ using selenium. However, I am getting stuck on the second page where there is a dropdown menu requiring you to select a top level domain. The dropdown menu is entirely made of divs and css, meaning none of the options have unique IDs, and seemingly cannot be interacted with using .click():

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

This is the entire HTML for the dropdown:
[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF1wk.png)

What can I actually do? I read about the Select class as well, but I assume it will have the same result, and the elements are not uniquely identifiable by ID so not sure it can be used either way.

Answer (score 0):

This will help. You can have array with all of the selections and just click the first one.

```py
Mas = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("dropdown__list-item")
Mas[1].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('dropdown__list_item selected')[option_you_want_to_click_index].click()
```